# sudo aws ubuntu 20.04 ami requires password

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am using default ubuntu 20.04 AMI in AWS: ami-08edbb0e85d6a0a07

When I type `sudo` it requires a password. What is it?

Notice I have SSH so it's not about credentials to login.

[image: ami selection]

Comment: Very strange... from what I understand, there should not be a password by default.  Any chance you set one - maybe via some process you ran?  Can you replicate it with a brand new instance?

Comment: Hi @chrisputnam9 yeah you can replicate it. I just did. I guess ubuntu.com is a proprietary company and not an official AMI by AWS although it looks as if it is.

Comment: which user do you use for the ssh connection? I was not able to reproduce your issue (using ssm to connect to the instance). I'm logged in as ssm-user and can co `sudo ...` without being asked for a password

Answer (score 5):

Usually, Amazon Linux doesn't ask for a password but on Ubuntu, you can encounter a password prompt as I did. I resolved the issue by one of the two alternatives:

1. Try `sudo passwd ubuntu` to set a new password. It won't ask the old password, just type and retype the new one. When you make an install or some other operation, it still asks the password but you know it now.
2. A better way, perhaps, is to type `sudo visudo` to open the  `/etc/sudoers.tmp` file. There, change the sudo group, which starts `%sudo`, as follows: `%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`. This change won't make the password prompt appear again.